# Facebook Connect PHP SDK - Differents accounts

Tags: php, database, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Facebook Connect (PHP SDK) in my website.

I have 2 kind of users to sing in new user in my website (Premium User and Normal User) and I want to offer Facebook Login to both insted fill new form.

If the user login with Facebook, but doesn't have a record in database, I have to do it, using its Facebook email. Premium Users are recorded in table1 and Normal Users are recorded in table2.

The question is: how can I dettect what user logged with Facebook to check if it's already recorded in its table (in Facebook returning page)?

Just to clarify: I have two forms (one for Normal User and another to Premium User), and each form has a Facebook Loggin button.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unintelligible. Please rephrase and explain what you mean by "2 kind of users".

Comment: Thanks for you attention! I updated my post.

Comment: You can simply look into table1 and see if the email exists there and if not look into table2. That seems simple enough but is this really your question?

Comment: No, my friend. I have to check in the right table, but how to do it if I don't know what user (Premium or Normal) have logged?

Comment: Just to clarify: I have two forms (one for Normal User and another to Premium User), and each form has a Facebook Loggin button.

Comment: If a user is logged in, are you not able to know whether they are a premium user as opposed to a normal user?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37792/discussion-between-sebastien-and-alan-gularte)

Answer (score 0):

Question solved!

```
require "facebook/src/facebook.php";

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        "appId"  => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "secret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
            try {
                $user_profile = $facebook->api("/me");
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                $user = null;
            }

        }else {
            $facebook_url_user_premium = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                    "scope" => "email",
                    "redirect_uri" => "https://URL"
            ));

            $facebook_url_user_normal = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                    "scope" => "email",
                    "redirect_uri" => "https://URL"
            ));
        }
```

So you call the correct $facebook_url.... variable in each Facebook Login button.